# JSON deserialization of a list of integers in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, javascriptserializer

I tried searching, but all the examples I found are of complex JSON with different things inside -- I can parse them OK to a class.

But how do I deserialize this simple list of integers/strings?

```
{"items":[1,2,3,4]}
```

Things like:

```
Dim temp = obj_JSSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of String))(s_JSONString)
```

don't work; same with deserializing to class with a list inside.

I'm using the `JavaScriptSerializer` from .NET 4.0

I suspect this is something very simple, but I'm still confused.

Comment: try `List(Of Int32)` the items are integers not strings (no quotes `""`)

Comment: Dim temp = obj_JSSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Int32))(s_DataString) - not helping "no children available".

Comment: its a class/type containing only a `List(Of Int32)`.  If you use NewtonSoft, you could pull out the `items` and deserialize to a list.  To use the NET JavaScriptSerializer, create the class

Comment: Thx for pushing in the right direction, I had to not only create the class, but remove one extra "of"- which was the mistake I stumbled upon: Dim temp = obj_JSSerializer.Deserialize(Of cls_HolderAPI1Items)(s_DataString) With the class containing " Public items As List(Of Int32)" Fixed.

Comment: you should post an actual answer

Answer (score 0):

I not only had to create the class, but remove one extra `Of`, which was the mistake I stumbled upon.

```
Dim temp = obj_JSSerializer.Deserialize(Of cls_HolderAPI1Items)(s_DataString)
```

The class definition looks like this:

```
Public Class cls_HolderAPI1Items
    Public items As List(Of Int32)
End Class
```

Everything is working now.

Comment: thats a very bad nomenclature ... class-names should never contain underscores nor numbers, and they should **always** start with an uppercase letter, everything else is just ... unreadable garbage. Sorry but its just like that. Also : use "camel-case", that'll help readability to a great extent - even if it may look weird sometimes ... its a simple psychological trick which enables the reader to understand semantics swiftly.